# Psycopg2 & Flask - tying connection to before_request & teardown_appcontext

Tags: flask, psycopg2

Cheers guys,
refactoring my Flask app I got stuck at tying the db connection to `@app.before_request` and closing it at `@app.teardown_appcontext`. I am using plain Psycopg2 and the app factory pattern.

First I created a function to call wihtin the app factory so I could use @app as [suggested by Miguel Grinberg here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xv-a-better-application-structure):

```
def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

    --

    from shop.db import connect_and_close_db
    connect_and_close_db(app)

    --

    return app
```

Then I tried this pattern suggested on http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/#storing-data:

```
def connect_and_close_db(app):

    @app.before_request
    def get_db_test():
        conn_string = "dbname=testdb user=testuser password=test host=localhost"
        if 'db' not in g:
            g.db = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
        return g.db

    @app.teardown_appcontext
    def close_connection(exception):
        db = g.pop('db', None)

        if db is not None:
            db.close()
```

It resulted in:

```
TypeError: 'psycopg2.extensions.connection' object is not callable
```

Anyone has an idea what happend and how to make it work?

Furthermore I wonder how I would access the connection object for creating a cursor once its creation is tied to `before_request`?

Comment: Can you show us the full traceback?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This solution is probably far from perfect, and it's not really DRY.  I'd welcome comments, or other answers that build on this.

To implement for raw `psycopg2` support, you probably need to take a look at the [connection pooler](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/pool.html).  There's also a [good guide](https://pynative.com/psycopg2-python-postgresql-connection-pooling/#psycopg2s_AbstractConnectionPool) on how to implement this outwith Flask.

The basic idea is to create your connection pool first.  You want this to be established when the flask application initializes (This could within the python interpreter or via gunicorn worker of which there may be several - in which case each worker has its own connection pool). I chose to store the returned pool in the config:

```
from flask import Flask, g, jsonify

import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import pool

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['postgreSQL_pool'] = psycopg2.pool.SimpleConnectionPool(1, 20,
    user = "postgres",
    password = "very_secret",
    host = "127.0.0.1",
    port = "5432",
    database = "postgres")
```

Note the first two arguments to `SimpleConnectionPool` are the `min` & `max` connections.  That's the number of connections going to your database server, bwtween `1` & `20` in this case.

Next define a `get_db` function:

```
def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = app.config['postgreSQL_pool'].getconn()
    return g.db
```

The `SimpleConnectionPool.getconn()` method used here simply returns a connection from the pool, which we assign to `g.db` and return.  This means when we call `get_db()` anywhere in the code it returns the same connection, or creates a connection if not present.  There's no need for a `before.context` decorator.

Do define your teardown function:

```
@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_conn(e):
    db = g.pop('db', None)
    if db is not None:
        app.config['postgreSQL_pool'].putconn(db)
```

This runs when the application context is destroyed, and uses `SimpleConnectionPool.putconn()` to put away the connection.

Finally define a route:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    db = get_db()
    cursor = db.cursor()

    cursor.execute("select 1;")
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print (result)

    cursor.close()
    return jsonify(result)
```

This code works for me tested against postgres runnning in a docker container.  A few things which probably should be improved:

- This view isn't very DRY.  Perhaps you could move some of this into the `get_db` function so it returns a cursor. (!!!)
- When the python interpreter exits, you should also find away to close the connection with `app.config['postgreSQL_pool'].closeall`
- Although tested some kind of way to monitor the pool would be good, so that you could watch pool/db connections under load and make sure the pooler behaves as expected.

*(!!!)In another land, the `sqlalchemy.scoped_session` [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html#using-thread-local-scope-with-web-applications) explains more things relating to this, with some theory on how its 'sessions' work in relation to requests. They have implemented it in such a way that you can call `Session.query('SELECT 1')` and it will create the session if it doesn't already exist.*

---

**EDIT**: Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/vulcan25/55ce270d76bf78044d067c51e23ae5ad) with your app factory pattern, and sample usage in the comment.

Comment: Had to switch order compared to your gist as I am using Blueprints. This forced me to place get_db() outside of create_app() for import into routes.py. Furthermore I had to change app.config[] to current_app.config[] within get_db() as outside of create_app() the app variable is not defined. DB responds however I had no time to check @app_teardown functionality yet. However since I did not need to touch that part of your solution and your gist implies it works I assume it will work for my solution as well.

Comment: @Dejell This was just a proof of concept, so no reason from me.  The [guide](https://pynative.com/psycopg2-python-postgresql-connection-pooling/#psycopg2s_AbstractConnectionPool) I linked outlines the features of each.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am using this pattern:
(I ll edit this answer eventually if I came up with better solution)

This is main script in which we use database. It uses two functions from config: `get_db()` to get connection from pool and `put_db()` to return connection into pool:

```py
from config import get_db, put_db
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def select():
    db = get_db()
    sleep(1)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    # Print select result and db connection address in memory
    # To see if it gets connection from another addreess on second thread
    cursor.execute("SELECT 'It works %s'", (id(db),))
    print(cursor.fetchone())
    cursor.close()
    put_db(db)

Thread(target=select).start()
Thread(target=select).start()
print('Main thread')
```

This is `config.py`:

```py
import sys
import os
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import pool
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

def get_db(key=None):
    return getattr(get_db, 'pool').getconn(key)

def put_db(conn, key=None):
    getattr(get_db, 'pool').putconn(conn, key=key)

# So we here need to init connection pool in main thread in order everything to work
# Pool is initialized under function object get_db
try:
    setattr(get_db, 'pool', psycopg2.pool.ThreadedConnectionPool(1, 20, os.getenv("DB")))
    print(color.red('Initialized db'))
except psycopg2.OperationalError as e:
    print(e)
    sys.exit(0)
```

And also if you are curious there is an `.env` file containing db connection string in `DB` env variable:

```
DB="dbname=postgres user=postgres password=1234 host=127.0.0.1 port=5433"
```

(`.env` file is loaded using `dotenv` module in `config.py`)